# Accessing a variable in a method in a cfc from a calling page

Tags: xml, solr, coldfusion

I have a method in a cfc which is making a cfhttp call like below. There is an issue with the cfc, which I need to debug.  I am using the below code to call the method to debug. But the writedump is as in the image below. I want to know how can I access local.search_result from outside the cfc and see what it is returning, in my debug code. When I make a direct cfhttp call to the below solr engine from a test page i get an error like below. I have not used solr or json or xml before. So please correct me if im wrong here.

[image]

```
<cfscript>
 myReturn = new cfcs.search().newsearch(criteria = 'congress', evidence_based_only = 'true'); 
 writedump(myReturn); 
 </cfscript>

<cfhttp url="#variables.search_url#" result="local.temp_result" /> <!--- may want to add some error-handling here --->
        <cfif local.temp_result.statusCode NEQ "200 OK" OR NOT isJSON(local.temp_result.fileContent)>
            <!--- Some sort of error - return out with no results --->
            <cfmail from="test@acs.com" to="test@sd.r5.com"
                subject="bad url"
                type="html"
            >The following search URL failed on #variables.SVR#: <a href="#variables.search_url#">#variables.search_url#</a></cfmail>
            <cfreturn this />
        </cfif>

        <cfset local.search_result = deserializeJSON(local.temp_result.fileContent) />


            <cfset local.max_score = local.search_result.response.maxScore />
            <cfset variables.result_cnt = local.search_result.response.numFound />
```

The url in cfhttp call is to a solr service like this

http://abcs.def.com:8983/solr/test/select?q=journal_name:congress&rows=100&sort=publish_dt%20desc
[image]

Comment: It seems as if you are attempting to deserialize a string that is not JSON. Can you show the rest of the error, the exact code that is throwing the error?

Comment: Dealing strictly with your prose, you should not be able to access variables inside a function from outside the function.  All the calling code should be able to see is what the function returns.  To debug the function, use the same tools for debugging anything else.  cfoutput and cfdump allow you to see what is going on, but you have to use them inside the function, then take them away when you have things figured out.

Comment: I tried  <cfdump var="#variables.search_url#"><cfabort> in the cffunction to see what solr url the cfhttp is calling. The page did not abort...Any idea how else can i dump the variable

Comment: If the page did not abort you may have put that code in a different function than the one you called.  Or, there may have been some conditional logic that prevented the dump/abort from executing.

Answer (score 3):

The content being returned by `local.temp_result.fileContent` is clearly XML judging by your error message, not JSON, so `deserializeJSON()` won't work with it.

You need to use `XmlParse()` instead to turn what is basically a block of text that looks like XML, into an actual XML object that ColdFusion can work with.

This:

```
<cfset local.search_result = deserializeJSON(local.temp_result.fileContent) />
```

Should become:

```
<cfset local.search_result = XmlParse(local.temp_result.fileContent) />
```

See these links for more info:

- https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/XmlParse
- http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/XML/
- https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion+XML+tag+and+functions

---

Also I'd question your use of isJSON() - is that returning true for your filecontent?  It looks like your code previously was getting back JSON and now it's returning XML, but you've simply not updated your CF code to match this.  I'd also recommend replacing isJSON with isXML.